# Unable to save JSON (GeoJSON) data in SQLite in Cordova

Tags: javascript, json, cordova

I have this code snippet below:

```
var json_data = document.getElementById("json_data").value;
console.log(json_data);

 tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO floodmaps VALUES (?,?,?)', [1, flodMapName, json_data], function(tx, res) {
     //console.log(res);
     console.log("rowsAffected: " + res.rowsAffected + " -- should be 1");
     //console.log(res.rows.item(0).flood_name);
   },
   function(tx, error) {
     console.log('INSERT error: ' + error.message);
   });

 tx.executeSql('SELECT *FROM floodmaps', [], function(tx, res) {
     //console.log(res);
     console.log(res.rows.item(0).id);
     console.log(res.rows.item(0).flood_name);
     console.log(res.rows.item(0).json_data);
   },
   function(tx, error) {
     console.log('error: ' + error.message);
   });
```

What it does is get the value from a `input` element then save that value into the database. But it does not save, this is the message in the debug console:

```
rowsAffected: 1 -- should be 1
main.js:208 null
main.js:209 null
main.js:210 null
main.js:241 Transaction Successful
```

But when I tried using sample data like just a plain text/word, it does save successfully. What could be the problem?

Here's the [data](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/75734877/FloodHazard_CRB_100Year.json).

Answer (score 0):

```
var json_data = document.getElementById("json_data").value;
console.log(json_data);
var str_json_data=JSON.stringify(json_data);  // my edits
 tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO floodmaps VALUES (?,?,?)', [1, flodMapName, str_json_data], function(tx, res) {
     //console.log(res);
     console.log("rowsAffected: " + res.rowsAffected + " -- should be 1");
     //console.log(res.rows.item(0).flood_name);

    if(res.rowsAffected>0){
     tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM floodmaps', [], function(tx, res) {
     //console.log(res);
       var len = res.rows.length, i;

            for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                console.log(res.rows.item(i));
            }
   },
   function(tx, error) {
     console.log('error: ' + error.message);
   });

      }
   },
   function(tx, error) {
     console.log('INSERT error: ' + error.message);
   });
```

> You have to stringify the json object before inserting

Comment: I already tried that, still returns null. The data is from remote server then saved in `input` element then retrieved.

Comment: Same, it returns null value. Must be the size of the data.

Comment: check my update , I think its becoz , you are always selecting the element of zeroth index .

Comment: Actually, I always drop the table if it exist as I am in development stage.